# chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId not working on enrolled chromebox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I'm building a chrome kiosk app in ReactJS that needs to access the deviceId of the device it is running on for logging purposes. I use the following code to call chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId:

```
const getDeviceId = (cb) => {
  if (!chrome.enterprise) {
    if (cb) {
      cb();
    }

    return;
  }

  // get device id
  chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(assetId => {
    deviceId = assetId;

    if (cb) {
      cb();
    }
  });
};
```

Afterwards, the function is called by doing something along these lines:

```
getDeviceId(() => {
  debug('Got device id: %s', deviceId);
});
```

Now, I know that this code can only work on a enrolled, ChromeOS device. I also know that the chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes is only available to extensions that are pre-installed by policy. Because of this I can only test it after it is submitted to the ChromeOS store and is installed via the developer dashboard.

Long story short: the above code doesn't return the deviceId and this causes all my api calls to fail, I can't really debug it because it gets installed as a kiosk app. I was wondering if anyone here could tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try debugging by running chrome --whitelisted-extension-id=....... The API may get enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was using the code as a synchronous function while it is an asynchronous function. For the correct usage, look at Tom Dunn's answer on here.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you might not have the "enterprise.deviceAttributes" permission declared in your manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "enterprise.deviceAttributes"
  ],
```

That permission is listed in top section of the APIs page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes#intro

I am running this JavaScript inside of the content window I create in my Chrome App and it works well:

```
chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDirectoryDeviceId(deviceId => {
    let publicDeviceId = document.getElementById('publicDeviceId');
    publicDeviceId.innerText = deviceId;
});
```

It returns the value shown on Chrome Devices detail page in management console > Device Management > Chrome Devices > device detail page - section: Hardware and OS > Directory API ID.  Its a GUID.

The API **does work for Chrome Apps** (which is the only place I've tested it) even though the documentation for the API redirects to the extensions page.

Comment: I upvoted you as you show the correct usage of the code, but my problem was acutally that I was using the code synchronously while it is asynchronous code. :) cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the permissions bit - that was the bit that I missed out which caused the API invocation to fail.

Comment: can anyone confirm that it works for extensions as well? I got no error, just empty reply..

Comment: @OliverWhite It should work for extensions since its documented under the /extensions but I have not tried.  It does only work on Chrome OS though "Important: This API works only on Chrome OS."

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your Chrome OS version is >= 66.  I lost a few hairs because of this.